# Conditional Proof in Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin\theta + \sin\alpha=m$ and $\cos\theta + \cos\alpha=n$, prove that:
$$\frac{\sec(\theta+\alpha)}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}{2}$$

My attempt\
given: $$\sin\theta+\sin\alpha=m$$
            $$2 \sin(\frac{\theta+\alpha}{2}) \cos(\frac{\theta-\alpha}{2})=m$$
         Again, using the transformation formula for the second condition:
$$2\cos(\frac{\theta+\alpha}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta-\alpha}{2})=n$$.My solution ends up here.

Comment: Are you sure it is $\frac{\sec(\theta+\alpha)}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}{2}?$ In such a case, why is not written as $\sec(\theta+\alpha)=\sqrt{m^2+n^2}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something wrong in the Question.

$$\dfrac{m^2+n^2}4=\dfrac{2+2\cos(\theta-\alpha)}4=\cos^2\dfrac{\theta-\alpha}2$$

Divide the first equation by the second to find $\tan\dfrac{\theta+\alpha}2=\dfrac mn$

Now use $\sec^2u=1+\tan^2u$

Comment: instead of 2 I got n in the debominator of R.H.S

Comment: @Iaamuseruser, Coud you follow my steps?

Comment: yes, i could follow that.